# CakePhp3 redirect from private method

Tags: redirect, cakephp, controller

I have this problem with **CakePhp3**:

In my controller I would like to do something like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{ 

   public function myAction1(){
    $this->initData();
    /* more code here */
   }

   public function myAction2(){
    $this->initData();
    /* more code here */
   }

   public function myAction3(){
    $this->initData();
    /* more code here */
   }

   /* more actions here */


   private function initData(){
    if ($this->validData()){
     /* complex code to initalize data */
    }else{
     /* REDIRECT TO FAIL URL */
    }
   }

   private function validData(){

     /* complex code to validate data */
     return $valid;

   }

}
```

**My question is:**

What code should I use instead of

**/* REDIRECT TO FAIL URL */**

to redirect the user to a different url?

Using:

return $this->redirect($url);

inside initData (ofcourse) doesn't work and I would like not to handle the redirect inside every action.

Comment: $this->redirect() works for me in CakePHP 3.6  $this->initData().

Comment: It won't work because return $this->redirect($url) inside initData would just return a response object to myAction1, myAction2, etc. It would work calling it from inside myAction1, myAction2, etc. but I would have to change them all and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in support for that (yet). It should be simple enough to implement this on your own, you could for example overwrite [`Controller::invokeAction()`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_invokeAction) to catch redirect exceptions, and make it return redirect responses accordingly, something like:

```
public function invokeAction()
{
    try {
        return parent::invokeAction();
    } catch (\Cake\Routing\Exception\RedirectException $exception) {
        return $this->redirect($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getCode());
    }
}

private function initData()
{
    if ($this->validData()) {
        // ....
    } else {
        throw new \Cake\Routing\Exception\RedirectException(
            \Cake\Routing\Router::url([/* ... */]), // redirect URL
            302 // HTTP status code
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not so simple but I'll try it out.